# HTML video on MacOS

Tags: macos, cross-browser, html5-video, cross-platform

Rendering of  on different browsers in all cases are not similar. I havent any crossbrowser problems on Windows by using FF, Chrome, Opera, but all of these in Mac Os give me a new color distort. Some browser render video lighter, some is dark, opera render it with a more blue. 
I tried to use JS - with canvas i get top/left pixel of video background and apply it to body but it didnt work in all browsers ( like in Opera ) and color what takes is not correct. Any idea of a correct solution to fix it? final task is - similar body and video bg. 
thanks[image: video origin bg is #474747]

Comment: If possible please share video file.

Comment: as example http://c3s.itmore.ru/video.php